# How to associate variables to an object and return them?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have 3 classes: Service, Client and Mess (which I should somehow refactor).

```
Class Service {

    void servicemethod(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        //does something with params a, b and c
    }
}
```

I have the client class which calls two methods from the same Mess

```
 Class Client {

    main()
    {
        Mess.setABC(x)
        Mess.callintermediatemethod(int x)
    }
}
```

The Mess class does nothing but reads params a, b and c, which are values associated with key "x" in a file, and calls `Service.servicemethod(a, b, c)`:

```
Class Mess {

    static void setABC(int x)
    {
        //sets static params a, b and c with values read from json file that has x as its key
    }

    void callIntermediatemethod(x)
    {
        Service.servicemethod(a, b, c);
        //here x parameter is not even necessary since it already knows what A, B and C are.
    }
}
```

Clearly, the Mess class does two things. Sets static variables after reading x and calls service method with the values stored, taking a dummy parameter. This clearly is bad design. But if I decide to do away with mess, how do I set the parameters a, b, c given the variable x? Should I associate them with an object? Decorate them? Use a builder pattern or a dependency injection? How to clean up Mess and make Client class directly call the service method without having to pass through Mess?

Comment: You should prefer to use non static methods and class instance variables unless you have a compelling reason that justifies static needs. Generally, what you have for the Mess class is a poor design. Take some time to read up on and take advantage of Object Oriented design.

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote, you're only using static method. You should use `beans` with a dependency injection framework (like spring). You might need a classs that contains ABC. Create a specific `bean` for reading the XML that will return an `ABC` from your `x`. Then you should directly call your `Service.servicemethod(myAbc);`

So it would be somthing like (I used different names for classes and objects, you should too because it's a little bit confused in your pseudo-code):

```
  public class Client{

    @Service("myXmlReader") //Spring service annotation
    MyXmlReader xmlRdr;

    @Service("myService")
    MyService srvce;

   int main(){
        int x = 12;
        MyABC abc= xmlRdr.readAbcFromX(x);
        srvce.serviceMethod(abc);
    }
    public class MyABC(){ //Shouldn't be an inner class but you get the idea
    int a; int b; int c;
    //getters and setters ...
    }
}
```

That's an example, that's how I would do on my current project, but it doesn't have to be so complicated. For instance, you might just instanciate the `MyXmlReader` as a Singleton, or just with a `new`, depending on what it does and needs. Same thing for `MyService`. So you wouldn't need to use Spring.

Dependency injection is what you need, but first you need to separate logic from your Mess, then use each units when they are needed (which class reads from file, from database, write to files, process business logic, only contains data, is called from outside, etc.).

You also mentionned "how do I set the context parameters a, b, c given the variable x", which is quite vague. Why would a b c be linked to a context ?

Comment: a,b,c are parameters associated with x. The "context" word was literal usage. Removed. :)